# DescribedTaskRenderer right to left

Tags: objectlistview

I tried to work with DescribedTaskRenderer that i set to RTL and it looks like.
[image: 1.png]
and i understand that DescribedTaskRenderer not support RTL as it say in the code
[image: 1.png]

the question is how i can make it work with RTL (what should i change in the code). and i dont need it to work in LTR mode just in RTL (i don't care if in the LTR it show bad)
thks for your help

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: nop just move to wpf :-)

Comment: Thanks... I am trying to avoid... My application is almost complete, This one requirement is stuck